# New users cannot login on live server, but can on local dev server (modx cms)

Tags: php, content-management-system, authentication, modx

I've been adding CMS functionality to a site using [modx](http://modxcms.com/) [Evolution 1.0.2](http://modxcms.com/download/). I've been doing this on my local dev server ([MAMP](http://mamp.info)) and recently put up a copy of the site on a shared host (Bluehost) and everything seems to be working fine except that new users cannot login (wrong username/password combination). Users that were created on my local dev server (and imported via SQL import) work fine as long as I don't change their passwords.

The way I deployed the site is by uploading the files via SFTP and then importing the DB from my local dev server. I then changed a few path settings as described in this outdated [moving guide](http://svn.modxcms.com/docs/display/Evo1/Moving+Site).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I had accidentally set the database collation to "ucs2_general_ci" instead of what my local dev server was set to, "utf8_general_ci". All the tables where correctly set, but not the database itself. Changing this seems to have fixed the problem. I'm not sure that this was it, but I guess it must be since nothing else changed.